# Save Setting onDestroy

Tags: android, save, android-lifecycle, setting, ondestroy

How to save setting after we exit the app using onDestroy?

Example:

When the app start, it will start Main_Activity.class

```
Button button1;

public class Main_Activity extends Activity {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     ................
}
```

Added a button named "button1" and give an Action to open new activity when clicked

```
public void button1_newactivity (View v){
     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View arg0) {
               Intent secondactivity=new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Second_Activity.class);
               startActivity(secondactivity);
          }
     });
}
```

Added 2 Checkbox on Second_Activity.class, as a default when the app start checkbox1 is selected and checkbox2 is not selected. But, when checkbox2 selected and checbox1 automatically not selected, after pressed another button it will start Third_Activity.class.

My Question is how can we save this setting, so when we exit the app, then start the app again, It will automatically start Third_Activity.class not Main_Activity.class like the first one?

What should we write in this part

```
protected void onDestroy(){
     ....................
}
```

Comment: are you calling your own `onDestroy()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [SharedPreferences](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html&ei=bjGFUdeLEoPtrAebyoHwCA&usg=AFQjCNFyaMlF7pqBKbWPbXr7H1Wg4gKaoA&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bmk) to store which will be your first activity. launch your launcher activity like before. But in there check the value you saved in sharedpreference. So if you find that you have to start 3rd activity from the oncreate of launcher start the third and finish the first one. For example

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(name);
     boolean b = pref.getBoolean("should_start_third", false);
     if(b){
        finish();
        start third activity
     }
     ................
}
```

Here in SharedPreferences i used a should_start_third boolean value to check if the third activity will start directly. this is by default false.

you have to save the value of shared preferences after the third checkbox is selected. to save use like following.

```
getSharedPreferences(name).edit().putBoolean("should_start_third", true).commit();
```

Comment: yah sure .. writing the concept in pseudo code.. will that be okay?

Comment: No problem just please give an example

Comment: what is the proble are you facing?? i wrote start third activity. write there the codes for your third activity start

Comment: so it should be startActivity(Third_Activity); ?

Comment: yes.. start third activit there.. If you have problem whit sharedpreferences learn it att firs

Comment: Could you please write the complete code by the sample above please? Still a little bit confused how to use that

Comment: sorry I wont write code for you ... here people need to try by theirselves. So i gave the idea... learn and code by yourself